# Div width of 100% doesn't take 100% of the page?

Tags: css, html, width

When I use 100% width on a div, it leaves space on top of and on both sides of the div.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!--Head-->
<head>
    <title>Music</title>
</head>
<!--Body-->
<body>
    <div style = "background-color: #0FCCB3; height: 10em; width: 100%;"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Turns into:

[image: Screenshot]

See the white spaces on the top and sides? How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 4):

This happens because the BODY element has a margin.

Add the following style:

```
<style>
body { margin: 0px; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset the browsers default styles. In this case, you can do

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

But I would recommend using normalize.css http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ to get a clean slate when starting a project.

Answer (score 0):

That's margin (or padding ) on the body element, just remove it

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Th53K/

Answer (score 0):

this comes from padding or margin values of the body tag. Remove them by:

```
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

Browsers apply some default styles, these can be different for different Browsers and Versions. To avoid surprises from browser defaults, you can use a [css reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)